# How many unit cubes were used to create the large cubes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The outside faces of a large cube are pointed . The large cube is then divided into unit cubes . There are exactly 125 unit cubes that have no paint . How many unit cubes were used to create the large cubes ?

Comment: abstract algebra!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let the big cube be $n\times n\times n$. When you strip off the outer layer of cubes that have some paint on them, you get a $(n-2)\times (n-2)\times (n-2)$ cube.

Comment: that means (n-2)^3 = 125 ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Which tells you $n-2$, which tells you $n$. Then the number of $1\times 1\times 1$ little cubes is $n^3$.